# html checkboxes to php

Tags: php, html, checkbox, fpdf

I have the following code for checkboxes in html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <h1 align='center'>Welcome to YRRHELP Channel </h1>
</header>
<section align = 'left'>

<h2> Register </h2>

    <form action = "form.php" method = "post">
<p>
 <label>Name of Order :</label>
   <input type="text" name = "order" />
   </p>
   <p>
   <label>Quantity :</label>
   <input type="text" name="quantity" />
   </p>
    <p>

    <label>Country:</label>
    <select name="country">    
<option>Choose country</option>
             <option>NIG</option>
             <option>ABJ</option>
             <option>DXB</option>
             <option>SHJ</option>
             <option>KSA</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>

   <label>Postcode :</label>
   <input type="text" name="dob" />
    </p>

<p>
     <label>Choose type of order :</label>

   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="to1" > Energy Bar<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="to2"> Tents <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="to3"> Canned foods <br>

   </p>
    <p>
   <label>Date :</label>
   <input type="date" name="date" />
   </p>
   <p>
   <textarea rows="8" cols="50" name="comment">Enter more details...</textarea>

   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />


   </form>
   </section>

   </body>

   </html>
```

And my whole php code is :

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php'); 

if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{

$order=$_POST['order'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$post=$_POST['dob'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];


require("fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",16);

$pdf->Cell(10,10,"UNHRD",0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Order :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,"$order",1,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Quantity :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,"$quantity",1,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Country :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,"$country",1,1,'C');

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                       //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Total order :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell( 70, 10, $check, 1, 1 );



    }
  }  

$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Date :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,"$date",1,1);

$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Comment :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(70,10,"$comment",1,1,'C');

$pdf->Output();

}

?>
```

There is no error know , but the checkboxes field doesn't show up in my pdf generated, I am using fpdf for that:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post your full html form

Comment: <form is missing the closing >

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this. All checkboxes chosen echo'd the selection in my test. Maybe your FPDF is failing you. How are you using this, as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `c:///file.xxx` in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost/demo/page.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @compcrk this is not the right way to act with questions. With your edit all previous answers have not sense. This is a public site. Questions and answers are available for future visitors. You have to rollback to previous question, mark your question as answered and then ask for a new question.

Comment: `var_dump($pdf);` what do you see?

Comment: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `[]` syntax for reading from an array: `[]` is syntax to append a new item to an existing array.

Your HTML code `name="check_list[]"` send three POST variables that php interprets as array, so — in php page — in `$_POST[check_list]` you will have a normal array with three elements.

Simply remove this line:

```
$t01=$_POST['check_list'][];
```

and — inside `foreach` loop — change this line:

```
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$t01",1,1);
```

in this way:

```
$pdf->Cell( 50, 10, $check, 1, 1 );
```

With your `foreach` through `$_POST['check_list']` you assign to `$check` each value of array items, so your desired value is already in `$check` variable.

Comment: I have done the following edits, there are no errors no but I have a problem, I have edited my question above,

Answer (score 1):

According to error `[]` is not for reading.It's for assigning values.

```
$t01=$_POST['check_list'];// no need for []
```

`$t01` will have whatever `$_POST['check_list']` has

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code sends back array of values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="to1" > Energy Bar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="to2"> Tents <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="to3"> Canned foods <br>
```

So in your PHP, you would use something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['check_list'])) 
{
    $t01 = $_POST['check_list'];
    $nCount = count($t01); // The count of boxes checked 
    echo "<p>";

    for ($k=0; $k < $nCount; $k++) {
        echo "Array element [".$k."] =".$t01[$k]."<br />";
    }
    echo "</p>";
}
```

Comment: How you will get if all three checkboxes are checked ?

Comment: Gives me an error: Notice: Undefined index: check_list in

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. They need the brackets as an array and for the `foreach`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, in my haste, I misread original HTML as Radio control.  Have changed my answer for future readers (and to hide my shame) because it is just academic now.  The edited / updated question looks nothing like original post.